# Verify question about complements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have the following question:

$$A = \big\{ x\in \mathbb{R} \mid x^3 < x^2\big\}$$

Write the set definition of $A^C$.

If I understand correctly, the complement of $A$ would be anything not in $A$, therefore the definition of $A^C$ would simply be $x^3 > x^2$. Is this logic correct?

Comment: Not quite. It should be $x^3\ge x^2$.

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I understand you, the (universal) complement of any set is really just, assuming that $U$ is the universal set:
$$A^C=U\setminus A.$$

Your question, however, asks for the set definition of $A^C$. Then, simply put, the definition of $A^C$ would be would be:
$$A^C = \left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x^3\geq x^2\right\}.$$